# Create a Systemd service in Ubuntu to run MKDocs

Tags: 20.04, systemd, services

I am running a server with MKDocs for documentation.

In order to use the MKDocs from the directory where the project is you need to run `mkdocs serve -a 192.168.3.107:8080` in order to get it to start.

So far I was using `/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s "MKDOCS" "cd /root/mkdocs && mkdocs serve -a 192.168.3.107:8080"` to have it run in the background but this is a very sketchy solution and I would like to run it as systemd Service.

I was trying something like this but it doesn't work:

```
[Unit]
Description=mkdocs service
ConditionPathExists=/root/mkdocs
[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin
ExecStart=/root/mkdocs serve -a 192.168.3.107:8080
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After I run the service with start, the status shows :

```
root@server:~/mkdocs# service mkdocs status
● mkdocs.service - mkdocs service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mkdocs.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-02-02 13:54:44 CET; 3min 46s ago
    Process: 379585 ExecStart=/root/mkdocs serve -a 192.168.3.107:8080 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 379585 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

I get journalctl -xe shows:

```
-- The job identifier is 368094.
Feb 02 13:54:44 server.domain.local systemd[379585]: mkdocs.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Feb 02 13:54:44 server.domain.local systemd[379585]: mkdocs.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /root/mkdocs: Permission denied
-- Subject: Process /root/mkdocs could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The process /root/mkdocs could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned by this process is ERRNO.
Feb 02 13:54:44 server.domain.local systemd[1]: mkdocs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mkdocs.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 203.
Feb 02 13:54:44 server.domain.local systemd[1]: mkdocs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mkdocs.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have given the directory full permissions with `chmod -R 777 /root/mkdocs` however I still get the same error.

Hopefully, someone can help me get it working. Thank you

EDIT:

I have Changed the path, still will 777 permissions, so the code now is:

however it still doesn't work, I am getting :

```
root@server:/test# systemctl daemon-reload
root@server:/test# systemctl start mkdocs.service
root@server:/test# systemctl status mkdocs.service
● mkdocs.service - mkdocs service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mkdocs.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-02-02 14:17:24 CET; 4s ago
    Process: 380128 ExecStart=/test mkdocs serve -a 192.168.3.107:8080 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 380128 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Feb 02 14:17:24 server.domain.local systemd[1]: Started mkdocs service.
Feb 02 14:17:24 server.domain.local systemd[380128]: mkdocs.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Feb 02 14:17:24 server.domain.local systemd[380128]: mkdocs.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /test: Permission denied
Feb 02 14:17:24 server.domain.local systemd[1]: mkdocs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 02 14:17:24 server.domain.local systemd[1]: mkdocs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

and `journalctl -xe` shows:

```
-- The unit mkdocs.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 02 14:20:32 server.domain.local systemd[1]: Started mkdocs service.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mkdocs.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mkdocs.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 368972.
Feb 02 14:20:32 server.domain.local systemd[380164]: mkdocs.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Feb 02 14:20:32 server.domain.local systemd[380164]: mkdocs.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /test: Permission denied
-- Subject: Process /test could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The process /test could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned by this process is ERRNO.
Feb 02 14:20:32 server.domainlocal systemd[1]: mkdocs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mkdocs.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 203.
Feb 02 14:20:32 server.domain.local systemd[1]: mkdocs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mkdocs.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
```

it doesn't make any sense since the permissions are 777.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? You seem to be on the right track. What happens with `sudo systemctl start mkdocs` or `sudo systemctl status mkdocs` ?

Comment: @Jos I edited the original question with more information, thanks for taking a look

Comment: It's a permissions problem. The executable has the wrong permissions, or you didn't start the service with `sudo`. In any case, `/root` is not a very good location for server executables.

Comment: @Jos I updated the post with EDIT, I changed the path and gave 777 permissions, but still having an issue. hopefully you can take a look. Thanks.

I belive the issue is the way I wrote the command. I am supposed to be In the directory where docs are, and run mkdocs, which is found : whereis mkdocs
mkdocs: /usr/local/bin/mkdocs /usr/share/man/man1/mkdocs.1.gz

Comment: @guiverc I updated the tags, I am actually testing on 20.04

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by creating script: `/root/mkdocs/run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /root/mkdocs
mkdocs serve -a 192.168.3.107:8080
```

And changing the service to:

```
[Unit]
Description=mkdocs service
ConditionPathExists=/root/mkdocs
[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env bash /root/mkdocs/run.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I'm leaving this answer in case someone looks for it in the future. file needs to be places in `/etc/systemd/system/mkdocs.service`